# Proposition 14.21 in the book "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Page number:$592$. In the Chapter Galois Theory, I have a doubt in one step of the following proposition:

**Proposition 21** Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be Galois extensions of a field $F$.

(1)The intersection $K_1 \cap K_2$ is Galois over $F$.

(2)The composite $K_1K_2$ is Galois over $F$. The Galois group is isomorphic to the subgroup
$H=\{ (\sigma ,\tau )|~\sigma|_{K_1\cap K_2} =\tau|_{K_1\cap K_2} \}$ of the direct product $Gal(K_1|F)\times Gal(K_2|F)$ consisting of elements whose restrictions to the intersection  $K_1\cap K_2$ are equal.

**I have a doubt on the proof of (2)** In one step there is a line

> The order of $H$ can be computed by observing that for every $\sigma \in Gal(K_1|F)$ there are $|Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)|$ elements $\tau \in Gal(K_2|F)$ whose restrictions to $K_1\cap K_2$ are $\sigma |_{K_1\cap K_2}$.

I don't know how to understand this step.
I also tried of proving this step by taking a $\sigma \in Gal(K_1|F)$ and a $\tau '\in Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)$ and constructing a $\tau \in Gal(K_2|F)$. For which I tried to prove  $\tau(a)$ =$\begin{cases} \sigma(a)&for~a\in K_1\cap K_2 \\\tau '(a) &for~a\in  K_2 -(K_1\cap K_2) \end{cases} $ is in $Gal(K_2|F)$, but unable to prove so.

**Is the way I am trying is right or there is any other simple proof of this step. Can anyone help be to understand this lines?**

Comment: There are two components in the statement: the fact that there exists at least one such $\tau$, and then the exact number. Once you show that the set of such $\tau$ is not empty, it is not hard to see that it is a class modulo $Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)$.

Comment: Are you suggesting Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory?

Comment: You can see it that way if you want. But you should not treat it as a mysterious black box, here it should be clear that if two automorphisms of $K_2$ coincide on $K_1\cap K_2$ it means that they are congruent modulo $Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)$.

Comment: First we have a $\sigma $ in $Gal(K_1|F)$. Then how to prove the existence of a $\tau $ in $Gal(K_2|F)$ which equals with $\sigma $ in the intersection $K_1\cap K_2$?  Also if the existence is proved once, how can you say there are modulo $Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)$ such $\tau $'s?   Also you are not looking for Fundamental Theorem which gives an isomorphism between $Gal(K_2|F)/ Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)$ and $Gal(K_1\cap K_2|F)$ given by $\sigma H \rightarrow \sigma |_{K_1\cap K_2}$, where $H=Gal(K_2|K_1\cap K_2)$ because $K_1\cap K_2|F$ is Galois, which is proved in another theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the isomorphism
$$Gal(K_1\cap K_2 / F) \cong Gal(K_2/F)\ /\ Gal(K_2 / K_1\cap K_2).$$
Hence, if $\sigma\in Gal(K_1/F)$, the restriction $\sigma_{\mid K_1\cap K_2}$ corresponds to a conjugacy class in said quotient, which has size $|Gal(K_2/K_1\cap K_2)|$.

Comment: You are using Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory.  I can understand now. Thank you!!